What exactly are cohesive and adhesive forces?
Are cohesive and adhesive forces defined only when at least one of the interacting materials is a fluid?

Wikipedia only states that the difference is if the molecules are alike vs not alike, which is the definition I normally know. I guess they are easier to see when one substance is a fluid.
